# For loop through DataTable and set values extremely slow

Tags: c#, database, loops, datatable, dataset

I have 2 objects, a `dataset.datatable` and a `sortedDictionary`. I have up to a couple of million records in my `dataset.datatable` and I need to check if every number that I have in my `sortedDictionary` exists in the `dataset.datatable`, if so I have to update that row's second column value (it's a boolean value).

```
foreach (var item in UpdatePhones)
{
    //Run through every record
    for (var i = 0; i < objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //Check if exists
        if (Convert.ToString(objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][0]) == item.Key)
        {
            //If so, update second column value
            objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] = item.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

My approach takes 1+ hour to update 3000 items in a 1,000,000 row `dataset.datatable`. Is there any faster approach?

> EDIT: I found a very simple solution, tho it blows my mind that it works both ways :S <

```
 foreach (var item in UpdatePhones)
 {
     DataRow[] row = objDataSet.Tables[0].Select("Number = " + item.Key);
     hrow[0][1] = item.Value;
 }
```

Comment: You're checking every item in UpdatePhones against the whole table. You only need to check the table against the dictionary until you find a match tho, right? Is there a 1:1 correspondence with the dictionary and the table, or do some values in the dictionary occur in the table multiple times? I would use PLINQ to select every row in the table that doesn't have an entry in the dictionary, you can then pass those rows to a function that updates their boolean value. It might be faster to read that column you're checking into its own collection first too.

Comment: Yes, I know i´m checking every item.... but I don´t know how to check the table against my dictionary.

I might have 1 million consecutive records, and 3000 numbers to check against it. "UpdatePhones" Dictionary contains only numbers that I already have in my database, also those numbers must all be updated

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide the correct column names for this to work.

```
    List<DataRow> rows = objDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
    var query = from row in rows.AsParallel()
        where UpdatePhones.Contains(Convert.ToString(row.Field<string>("Phone")))
        select row;
    query.ForAll((r) => UpdateThePhone(r));


    void UpdateThePhone(DataRow row)
    {
        row.SetField("YourBooleanColumn", true);
    }
```

I had to make some guesses, like assuming that when the value is in the dictionary and table you set the second column to true. Your code that you provided also doesn't set that value to false when the dictionary doesn't have the string either.

Comment: I eddited my code with a solution, it runs through each number to update and fills a DataRow when its found, then I set that rows second column value and after all I update the database with a DataAdapter... and it works! 

> I find so strange that I create a column and it magically runs backwards and updates my dataset :D